# How to build a tree from a flat list in FP JS

Tags: javascript, algorithm, functional-programming

I'm learning Functional Javascript and encounter into a problem.
I have this flat object:

```
const data = [
                    {id: 1, name: "Folder1", parentId: null},
                    {id: 2, name: "Folder2", parentId: null},
                    {id: 3, name: "Folder3", parentId: 1},
                    {id: 4, name: "Folder4", parentId: 2},
                    {id: 5, name: "Folder5", parentId: 3},
                    {id: 6, name: "Folder6", parentId: 3}
]
```

I desire to convert it to this hierarchical object, using only pure functions, no fors, ifs and other "imperative style statements".

Result should be:

```
    [{
        id: 1,
        name: "Folder1",
        parentId: null,
        children = [{
            id: 3,
            name: "Folder3",
            parentId: 1,
            children = [{
                    id: 5,
                    name: "Folder5",
                    parentId: 3
                },
                {
                    id: 6,
                    name: "Folder6",
                    parentId: 3
                }
            ]
        }]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Folder2",
        parentId: null,
        children = [{
            id: 4,
            name: "Folder4",
            parentId: 2
        }]
    }
]
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: `if` is not per se a bad thing. However, in Javascript it is implemented as a statement and statements don't return anything. But when you use it within a function, it is usually ok.

Answer (score 4):

This is a proposal without `if`, but with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). It needs a sorted array.

```js
var data = [{ id: 1, name: "Folder1", parentId: null }, { id: 2, name: "Folder2", parentId: null }, { id: 3, name: "Folder3", parentId: 1 }, { id: 4, name: "Folder4", parentId: 2 }, { id: 5, name: "Folder5", parentId: 3 }, { id: 6, name: "Folder6", parentId: 3 }],
    tree = data
        .reduce(
            (m, a) => (
                m
                    .get(a.parentId)
                    .push(Object.assign({}, a, { children: m.set(a.id, []).get(a.id) })),
                m
            ),
            new Map([[null, []]])
        )
        .get(null);

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Or the same as above using ES2015 destructuring assignment. It needs a sorted array and *also* depends on the input data having only `id`, `name` and `parentId` keys.

```js
var data = [{ id: 1, name: "Folder1", parentId: null }, { id: 2, name: "Folder2", parentId: null }, { id: 3, name: "Folder3", parentId: 1 }, { id: 4, name: "Folder4", parentId: 2 }, { id: 5, name: "Folder5", parentId: 3 }, { id: 6, name: "Folder6", parentId: 3 }],
    tree = data
        .reduce(
            (m, {id, name, parentId}) => (
                m
                    .get(parentId)
                    .push({id, name, parentId, children: m.set(id, []).get(id) }),
                m
            ),
            new Map([[null, []]])
        )
        .get(null);

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Of course this should probably be written as a reusable function ...

```js
var data = [{ id: 1, name: "Folder1", parentId: null }, { id: 2, name: "Folder2", parentId: null }, { id: 3, name: "Folder3", parentId: 1 }, { id: 4, name: "Folder4", parentId: 2 }, { id: 5, name: "Folder5", parentId: 3 }, { id: 6, name: "Folder6", parentId: 3 }];

// pure, reusable function
var buildTree = (data) =>
  data.reduce(
    (m, {id, name, parentId}) => (
      m
        .get(parentId)
        .push({id, name, parentId, children: m.set(id, []).get(id) }),
      m
    ),
    new Map([[null, []]])
  )
  .get(null);

console.log(buildTree(data));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Lastly, *if* the data is arriving in an unsorted order, we could handle sorting with a custom comparator

```js
// unsorted data example
var data = [{ id: 6, name: "Folder6", parentId: 3 }, { id: 2, name: "Folder2", parentId: null }, { id: 3, name: "Folder3", parentId: 1 }, { id: 4, name: "Folder4", parentId: 2 }, { id: 5, name: "Folder5", parentId: 3 }, { id: 1, name: "Folder1", parentId: null }];

// immutable sort
var sort = (f,xs) => [...xs.sort(f)];

// custom tree comparator
var treeComparator = (x,y) =>
  x.parentId - y.parentId || x.id - y.id; 

// sort data, then reduce
var buildTree = (data) =>
  sort(treeComparator, data).reduce(
    (m, {id, name, parentId}) => (
      m
        .get(parentId)
        .push({id, name, parentId, children: m.set(id, []).get(id) }),
      m
    ),
    new Map([[null, []]])
  )
  .get(null);

console.log(buildTree(data));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Good use of `Map`, clever use of `()` expression. This is the kind of answer you can expect from Nina; code that shines with elegance and immediately dissolves the complexity presented by others – I added a destructuring example that I think improves the readability a little bit. I hope you'll agree it serves the answer well and maintains its usefulness. Feel free to rollback otherwise ^_^

Comment: Interesting, I see this as introducing complexity, such as restraints not outlined in the original OP as well as introducing additional data structures. I personally would not be comfortable submitting this as an "answer" for that reason. I however do respect the submission, since the point of this question was an exercise.

Comment: @TimConsolazio despite the fact that the provided data is sorted in the order needed for Nina's answer to work, *if* the data were somehow unsorted, sorting could easily be accomplished in a separate function and then composed into this solution. Functional programming is about managing complexity by separating concerns and abstracting complexity into smaller functions and then composing them together. It would be silly to bundle all of that up into a single function.

Comment: @TimConsolazio, furthermore, the use of an additional data structure (Map) is perfect in this case as its use is a *localized* implementation detail and not leaked to the user – ie, when calling Nina's function, the user would have no idea that Map was used to derive the answer. The user of the function does not need to be concerned with such details – it is *by design* that functions give you the power to hide this from other parts of your program. It allows the function to change independent of the calling code.

Comment: @NinaScholz, I'm sorry to have attracted contention to your wonderful answer. I hope all edits address the criticisms in a way that you'd agree with.

Comment: Lol I think it's pretty clear what's going on here. You have a nice day. Let's try to keep the peace, maybe we just leave each other be.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with recursive function but you need to loop array with `reduce` and use `if` statements.

```js
const arr = [
  {id: 1, name: "Folder1", parentId: null},
  {id: 2, name: "Folder2", parentId: null},
  {id: 3, name: "Folder3", parentId: 1},
  {id: 4, name: "Folder4", parentId: 2},
  {id: 5, name: "Folder5", parentId: 3},
  {id: 6, name: "Folder6", parentId: 3}
]

function buildTree(data, pId) {
  return data.reduce(function(r, e) {
    var e = Object.assign({}, e);

    if (e.parentId == pId) {
      var children = buildTree(data, e.id)
      if (children.length) e.children = children
      r.push(e)
    }
    return r;
  }, [])
}

console.log(buildTree(arr, null))
```

Comment: Nice, thank you. But again, we have here IFs and temp variables deceleration.  I'm looking for a pure FP solutaion

Comment: What is the problem with ifs (or the ternary operator as in other answer) and temporary variables as long as you have immutability?

Comment: I don't think there's any problem, the OP is looking at this as an exercise.I've been doing more off this as well, working at changing my style. For example, the ternary operator is used as op/noop, which is something I picked up in scala, typically it's used to explicitly set a value.

Comment: @TimConsolazio *"[ternary is] typically used to explicitly set a value"*? – ternary operator forms an expression which can be part of any other expression

Comment: Yes...? Not sure what you're getting at. The practical use of ternary operators is to say, set this variable to this or that value based on this condition. Myself, I never see it used to say, "based on this condition, either execute this op, or do nothing at all." That's always performed with an imperative "if", which the author said he wanted to avoid.

Comment: @TimConsolazio these comments have little to do with Nenad's answer. I left a follow-up comment on your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = [
   {id: 1, name: "Folder1", parentId: null},
   {id: 2, name: "Folder2", parentId: null},
   {id: 3, name: "Folder3", parentId: 1},
   {id: 4, name: "Folder4", parentId: 2},
   {id: 5, name: "Folder5", parentId: 3},
   {id: 6, name: "Folder6", parentId: 3}
];

function trampoline ( f ) {
    while ( f && f instanceof Function ) { f = f ( ); }
    return f;
}

function buildTree ( data, copy, top = [] ) {

    function recur ( data, copy, top ) {
        copy = copy || data.concat ( [] );
        let current = copy.shift ( );
        current ? doWork ( ) : null; 

        function doWork ( )  {
            top = top.concat ( ( ! current.parentId ? current : [] ) );
            current.children = copy.filter ( x => { return current.id === x.parentId } );
        }

        return ( current ? recur.bind ( null, data, copy, top ) : top );
    }

    return trampoline ( recur.bind ( null, data, copy, top ) );
}

data.map ( x => { x [ 'children' ] = [ ]; return x; } );
console.log ( buildTree ( data ) );
```

Comment: Edited (because I've had some strong coffee) to trampoline, so the recursion doesn't fill up the stack. Should be able to do a pretty massive tree this way. Be nice when tail recursion gets implemented across the board some day and you can do this without the trampoline. If the game is just to have no ifs or loops you can just leave that out, these days though I'm trying never to write a recursive function without it if possible. You could always just consider trampoline a higher order function though.

Comment: Ternary operator has many practical uses besides setting a variable... `w => x ? y : z`, `f (x ? y : z)` just to demo a couple. Anyway, using it like you did is a cheap workaround of `if` even tho it's doing exactly the same thing. It's arguably *worse* because it forces you to specify a null noop on one of the branches. Using ternary in this fashion doesn't make the resulting code somehow less imperative and more functional – Aside from that, this answer still uses heaps of imperative style, assignment, *re*assignment, and mutation – Oh and why `f && ...` in the trampoline? Just drop that.

Comment: Don't infer that I mean assignment and mutation are somehow not allowed in a functional program. Rather, I think you make awkward tradeoffs in a genuine attempt to answer the question with the (albeit misguided) criteria, yet still end up with an answer that fails to meet the criteria. – Maybe my remarks belong on codereview.se and maybe this question belongs on codegolf.se; either way I think this is not a good answer.

Comment: You're entitled to your opinion of course. This was intended as an exercise and that's the spirit I took it in, I don't think in practice anybody would fire you for throwing an "if" in here. Myself, I tend to credit somebody for trying rather than admonishing them. Do as you please though.

Comment: I've been on SO for a long time and I've struggled with *how* to use the upvote button in the past, but now I just follow what is recommended by the button itself. If you mouseover the voting buttons, they read *"this answer is useful"* and *"this answer is not useful"* – at its best, your answer demonstrates the use of a trampoline and *why* you'd use it, which is not really what the question is about; at its worst, your answer has some over-the-top complexity happening (described above). – if the upvote button were to say *"this user tried"*, I promise I would've given you an upvote.

Comment: Me, I tend to say, "it might not be what I'm looking for, but it does give me some ideas, and others in the community seem to find it useful." 

I think I've downvoted one, maybe two answers ever, only because they were so completely off base or the code was just completely broken. Originally BTW I did post without the trampoline, but since tail recursion is a typical functional language capability and JS doesn't have it yet (browsers), this is the way, and I thought that detail might be useful to somebody moving towards a more functional style. I tried, you slammed, meh so be it.

Comment: That's the trouble with qualitative things; people see them differently. I agree that your answer does have value and is qualitatively useful, but on the same token, it's paired up with other things that have low value and are qualitatively not useful, to downright (qualitatively) *bad* advice, imo. A beginner/learner is not going to be able to distinguish the difference between good and bad. The net effect of these qualitative measurements is below neutral usefulness, and therefore I voted accordingly.

Comment: Fortunately some would seem to disagree. I guess that's the magic of SO. For the record I think your assessment also falls below qualitatively useful, since you do not downvote an answer here that explicitly ignores the OP. You are not reacting to the quality of the answers, you are reacting to the fact somebody upvoted an answer you don't have a high opinion of, suggesting some other motive beyond answer quality. Anyway, enough of this, do as you will.

Comment: Of course not everyone agrees; everyone's qualitative measurements are different ! You've been a user for almost 2 years – there's *heaps* of bad questions and answers on this site. To only have downvoted 1 or 2 is negligent, imo. I sincerely commend you for making an effort to educate, but that doesn't mean that everything you produce will be of *upworthy* value. In fact, the only reason I left a comment is because I could see you put substantial effort into your answer. I otherwise just would've left a downvote and moved on with my day.

Comment: The downvote is less about you and more as a flag/warning/indicator for learners – *"Beware, this answer is not unanimously voted as a good/recommended/practical solution"*

Comment: The horse is dead, we disagree, I think that as an exercise the answer has value, evidently at least one other person does (the OP I believe, who IMHO should be the one with the right to formally downvote, whereas commentors should have the right to "discourage" or some such), you don't and you wanted to make sure we all know it (your "warning"), and you've succeeded. As far as I can see we've both achieved our ends, and can move on with our days.

Comment: I'm sad that you feel personally attacked by this. It's counterproductive and renders time a waste for all parties involved.

Comment: Ok. Thank you, have a great day.